# Copy a file from res/raw to SDcard to send using Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-sdcard, fileoutputstream

The intention is to copy a file from the raw folder of my apk to the SDcard so that it may then be transferred to the users selected app using Intent.createChooser.  The file will be an example.ogg file that's already in the res/raw folder.

I've tried a dozen or so variations supplied by answers on stackoverflow but can't get anything to work...

This was an interesting attempt.

```
    public void playSound1(View view) {
        exampleSound.start();
        if (cb.isChecked()){



            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("audio/ogg");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///android:asset/example.ogg"));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
        }
    }
```

If selecting the text option from the chooser it would just tell me file type wasn't supported.  If however, I choose Gmail it would open Gmail app and show that the file attachment was there but when I sent the file to myself it would toast "unable to attach file".

After researching a bit it looks like things changed with lollipop that are making accessing raw files more complicated.  The work around is to copy the resource file to the SDcard then delete the file when your app is closed.  The reason for deleting file when app is closed is you need the file to exist until the chooser app has completed it's transfer.

Here's what I have.

ActivityMain.java snippet

```
    public void playSound2(View view) throws IOException {
        exampleSound.start();

        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.example1);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS));
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;

        try {
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                out.write(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Here's the AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.anjosoft.demo">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

I've tested by inserting exampleSound.start(); after each line and it plays until I place it after the FileOutputStream.  App crashes then.  How can I write to SDcard?

Comment: Unclear. If the file is in `/res/raw`, it's already **inside** your app. Meaning that your app users already have that file - no need to send it themselves

Comment: they will "share" it with somebody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding write external storage permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: holy cow the READ permission was supposed to be WRITE.  Can't believe I did that...